# Updating any UI’s List Control’s ItemSource via adding to ObservableCollection using MVVM causing Performance Hit

Tags: wpf, performance, merge, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` property in `ViewModel` bound with `ItemSource` of List Control in the UI.

In order to update the number of items displayed in List Control on runtime, I am adding the items in the `ObservableCollection` property in `ViewModel`. I have used two different type of code-snippets, which I am sharing below, but still, it is taking a huge amount of time to reflect the updated data in the List Control.

Code Snippet 1:

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);           
        }
}
```

Code Snippet 2:

```
void BatchAddPeople(IEnumerable<Person> newPeople)
{
    var currentPeople = _people;

    // stop WPF from listening to the changes that we're about
    // to perform
    this.People = null;

    // change
    foreach (var person in newPeople)
    {
        currentPeople.Add(person);
    }

    // cause WPF to rebind--but only once instead of once for
    // each person
    this.People = currentPeople; //Updating the ObservableCollection property with complete list
}
```

I have tried both these approaches using `BackGroundWorker` thread with updating of `ObservableCollection` code inside the `Dispatcher.Invoke` method, still I am facing performance issues.

Do you guys have any idea on how to reduce the performance hit in this case?

Comment: If you do `this.People = new ObservableCollection<Person>(newPeople)`, do you get any benefit?  Another idea is to use Virtualization.

Comment: If you want to improve the performance write your custom class that derivates from ObservableCollection, suppress the firing of the CollectionChanged event for the time you adding items to the list but befor adding the last one allow the event to be executed again.

Comment: @LeonidTsybert: First suggestion does not any improvement. For the second one, can you elaborate what do you mean by virtualization?

Comment: @ninjahedgehog: I have this collection bound to a list box where I dynamically add or remove objects from item source. So suppressing collection changed might not suffice.

Comment: It will you just dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that your 'performance hit' as you call it, is caused by the code that you showed us? In my opinion, the majority of time that a WPF application takes to load data is actually taken up by the rendering engine.

If you use a `Stopwatch` to measure the amount of time that it takes for your for loops to complete, I'm fairly sure that it won't be long at all... probably not even a quarter of a second for 50,000 objects or more:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    this.Items.Add(item);           
}
stopwatch.Stop();
TimeSpan elapsedTime = stopwatch.Elapsed; // I'm guessing this will not be a long time
```

Comment: I think the issue the OP talks about is collectionchanged event being fired on each add that causes the listbox to remeasue and redraw. maybe there he thinks he loses a second. I would suggest to use a profiler to find out exactly about the performance loss